# How to get author (year) clickable references while including pagebackrefs links in bibliography in lyx

Tags: lyx, natbib

I am going crazy trying to get what seems somewhat simple to me.  Right now, I have clickable references with hyperlinks back to the pages the citation occurs on.

I want to simply change it so the references appear as clickable Author (Year) (and Author Year when already inside parentheses) while retaining the page links in the biblio. Ideally this looks like the following:

[image]

Where the links back to the pages look like this (e.g., when you click the "2" it takes you back to page 2 where the reference occurred in the main text):

[image]

My current lyx settings are:

[image]

With this in the latex preamble:

```
\RequirePackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,      
    urlcolor=blue,
    pagebackcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue
}

\usepackage{natbib}
```

The problem is that the references are just numbers.

How do I retain the best of both worlds? How do I get the clickable Author (Year) and keep the clickback links?

When I change "variant" to author-year, it does the below:

[image]

EDIT:

Does it matter what style the biblio is via the below setting?:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the “variant” from “author-number” to “author-year”?

Comment: @Mico, yes I have. It does something weird when I do this, see the edit in the main post.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a lyx user. (But I'm reasonably proficient with BibTeX and natbib -- and LaTeX in general.) After changing the argument of "variant", did you perform a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more?

Comment: If you want author-year citations, you need to select "author-year" (or "author-date", I don't know the terminology that LyX uses) in the menu. If you then get errors or bold "**author?**" output that usually has broadly one of two reasons: (1) Your selected bibliography style is incompatible with `natbib` author-year citations. In the screenshot you selected the `natbib` style `plainnat`, which of course is compatible with `natbib` (so that is not the issue here). (2) Some of your `.bib` entries are missing an `author` field. Obviously, this citation style needs author and year.

Comment: @moewe  All of the references definitely have authors and years, so my guess is plainnat isn't compatible or something.

Comment: Well, `plainnat` (the style from the first screenshot) is definitely compatible. But `naturemag` (the style in the second screenshot)  may not be. Do things work if you select `plainnat` there as well?